# we can't find products matching the selection on filter side

Tags: magento2.4.3

i am having this message on filter side even though my products are showing.
[image: please help]

Answer (score 0):

First double-check the filter criteria,

If it is still shows that error message , Make sure that the product attribute that you are using for filtering is set to "Use in Layered Navigation" in the product attribute settings. If it is not set to "Use in Layered Navigation", the filter will not work correctly.

Comment: hello thanks for your replu, can you please share a path where i can change to layered navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the path

1.Log in to your Magento Admin Panel.

2.Go to Stores > Attributes > Product.

3.Find the attribute that you want to use for layered navigation and click on it.

4.Scroll down to the "Storefront Properties" section.

5.Look for the "Use in Layered Navigation" option and make sure it is set to "Filterable (with results)" or "Filterable (no results)" depending on your preference.

6.Click on the "Save Attribute" button in the upper-right corner of the page to save your changes.

Comment: yess i got the path, but there are too many attributes, some are already "filtered with navigation " and some are set to "no", now i am confused how which one should i set to filtered with navigation

Comment: Determining which attributes to set as "Use in Layered Navigation" depends on your specific products and your customers' needs.